# How to extract year and month from date in PostgreSQL without using to_char() function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select sql:
`SELECT "year-month" from table group by "year-month" AND order by date`, where 
year-month - format for date "1978-01","1923-12".
**select to_char of couse work**, but not "right" order:

```
to_char(timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Why is order not right with to_char?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because it's not clear why to_char() is not acceptable.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
date_part(text, timestamp)
```

e.g.

```
date_part('month', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40'),
date_part('year', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Comment: how to extract month and year at once?can you show an example

Comment: date_part('month', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40'), date_part('year', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but can't we do it in single function or do we have to call it twice for month and year separately

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Just get a string?  Then use to_char function with a date format you need https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 327):

```
to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
```

You say that the order is not "right", but I cannot see why it is wrong (at least until year 10000 comes around).

Comment: if you are working with "timestamp" to_char(to_timestamp(e."timestamp"), 'MM-YYYY')

Comment: @BrunoMarinho if you want a chronological order, then just don't use 'MM-YYYY for ordering'. If you want that displayed you can still have a column in that format but don't order by it

Comment: I don't understand why it is not the accepted answer.

Comment: In this case, you can't  `ORDER BY` date.

Comment: @Aviator: You can use `ORDER BY to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')`. Or alternatively if you did `SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') AS date` you can then simply use `ORDER BY date`.

Comment: Year 10000 is gonna gnarly

Comment: @JerryD This reminds me of when they increased the VAT (Value Added Tax) in South Africa to 15%. Hundreds of developers had hardcoded the value as 14%, because they didn't expect it to ever change - as it had been the same value for over 25 years. Boy, was that a hilarious shit show :D

Comment: if you want to re-use the date further down the line (e.g.: to add a time interval to it, say a few months) you won't be able to, because it's no longer a timestamp but a text.

Comment: To convert back to a timestamp: `SELECT to_timestamp('2019-01', 'YYYY-MM');`

Comment: Hi I want to display date as 1st dec 2020 how to format this

Comment: @SunilKumar that's a completely different question. Probably give a different second argument to to_char

Comment: Please note that to_char() function is supported only in PostgreSQL 11 and higher.

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon That seems unlikely as the question and answer appear to predate PostgreSQL 11, which was only released in 2018 according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/11.0/

Answer (score 58):

Use the [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) method to truncate off the day (or whatever else you want, e.g., week, year, day, etc..)

Example of grouping sales from orders by month:

```
select
  SUM(amount) as sales,
  date_trunc('month', created_at) as date
from orders
group by date
order by date DESC;
```

Comment: That's right. U can use to compare: 
     date(date_trunc( 'month', now())) = to_Date(5::varchar || ' ' || 2017::varchar, 'mm YYYY')

Comment: Twice as fast than "to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')" which is good too.

Answer (score 50):

You can truncate all information after the month using [`date_trunc(text, timestamp)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
select date_trunc('month',created_at)::date as date 
from orders 
order by date DESC;
```

---

**Example:**
**Input:**

```
created_at = '2019-12-16 18:28:13'
```

**Output 1:**

```
date_trunc('day',created_at)
// 2019-12-16 00:00:00
```

**Output 2:**

```
date_trunc('day',created_at)::date 
// 2019-12-16
```

**Output 3:**

```
date_trunc('month',created_at)::date 
// 2019-12-01
```

**Output 4:**

```
date_trunc('year',created_at)::date 
// 2019-01-01
```

Comment: How to do `date_trunc('month',created_at)` and return only 'YYYY-mm'?

Answer (score 26):

1st Option

```
date_trunc('month', timestamp_column)::date
```

It will maintain the date format with all months starting at day one.

Example:

```
2016-08-01
2016-09-01
2016-10-01
2016-11-01
2016-12-01
2017-01-01
```

2nd Option

```
to_char(timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM')
```

This solution proposed by @yairchu worked fine in my case. I really wanted to discard 'day' info.

Answer (score 18):

You Can use EXTRACT function pgSQL

```
EX- date = 1981-05-31
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
it will Give 5
```

For more details
[PGSQL Date-Time](https://singhak.in/how-to-extract-year-and-month-from-date-in-postgresql/)

Comment: OP said "year and month", not just "year".

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, to add year we can just change MONTH to YEAR and input the desired year. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

It is working for "greater than" functions not for less than.

For example:

```
select date_part('year',txndt)
from "table_name"
where date_part('year',txndt) > '2000' limit 10;
```

is working fine.

but for

```
select date_part('year',txndt)
from "table_name"
where date_part('year',txndt) < '2000' limit 10;
```

I am getting error.

Comment: It is working for greater than functions not for less than.

For example:

select date_part('year',txndt) FROM "table_name" where date_part('year',txndt) > '2000' limit 10; is working fine.

but for select date_part('year',txndt) FROM "hpi_validator_q3"."cdm_inv_exceptions" where date_part('year',txndt) < '2000' limit 10;

I am getting error.

Comment: This isn't an answer - if you have a question rather post a new question than adding your question as an answer.