# How to Extract Year from DATE in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

Date is in 'YYYY-MM-DD' text format, now I need to extract the year part which must be in numeric. I need this conversion to be done in single step, Since I need to use in other application where i cannot create new variable.

TO_DATE(t0.AESTDTC,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD' with this i was able to convert to date but Now i need to Extract the year from this date in single step? can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract year and month from date in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531577/how-to-extract-year-and-month-from-date-in-postgresql)

Comment: `extract(year from ...)`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT But you should ***NOT*** store dates as strings!

Answer (score 207):

Try

```
select date_part('year', your_column) from your_table;
```

or

```
select extract(year from your_column) from your_table;
```

Comment: the user may need to cast the string as date first.

Comment: How would I update the original date column with the output from this select statement?

Comment: @spacedSparking, in this case you would need to build a date string using those functions within a TO_DATE() or TO_TIMESTAMP(). Usually not pretty sights

Answer (score 21):

This line solved my same problem in postgresql:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', column_name::date) from tableName;
```

If you want *month*, then simply replacing `year` with `month` solves that as well and likewise.

Comment: How is this different to the other answers? And the cast to date is unnecessary - at least with a proper data model  where `column_name` is a proper `timestamp`

Answer (score 12):

Choose one from, where `:my_date` is a string input parameter of `yyyy-MM-dd` format:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(:my_date AS DATE));
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', CAST(:my_date AS DATE));
```

Better use `CAST` than `::` as there may be conflicts with input parameters.

Comment: The cast to a date is unnecessary

Answer (score 11):

answer is;

```
select date_part('year', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') as year,
       date_part('month', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') as month,
       date_part('day', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') as day,
       date_part('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') as hour,
       date_part('minute', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') as minute
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try `to_char(now()::date, 'yyyy')`
If text, you've to cast your text to date `to_char('2018-01-01'::date, 'yyyy')`

See the `PostgreSQL` Documentation [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: `to_char(now()::date, 'yyyy')` can be simplified to `to_char(now(), 'yyyy')`

Comment: hmm no need to cast here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY')
```

Comment: Why can't we just do this ``my_date_column::year``?