# How to fetch only year from date in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this in postgresql:

| Name | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | '2011-03-03' |
| XYZ | '2009-01-01' |

What is the query that I should use to get the output data in the below format(only year instead of date) also I want to retrieve data that is greater than 2010 only:

| Name | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | '2011' |

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531577/how-to-extract-year-and-month-from-date-in-postgresql-without-using-to-char-fu or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203613/how-to-extract-year-from-date-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format DOB using `to_char`.

```
select "Name", to_char(DOB, 'yyyy') DOB 
from the_table
where extract('year' from DOB) > 2010;
```

If DOB is character rather than `date` type then it has to be first cast to `date`:

```sql
select "Name", to_char(DOB::date, 'yyyy') DOB 
from the_table
where extract('year' from DOB::date) > 2010;
```

If your date represented as text has "month/day/year" format then use `to_date` to convert it to `date`.

```sql
select "Name", to_char(to_date(DOB, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy') DOB 
from the_table
where extract('year' from to_date(DOB, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) > 2010;
```

Unrelated but do *not* store dates as formatted text. You have data type `date` for this.

Comment: I am getting this error:                                           
                       (psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow) date/time field value out of range: "06/27/2022"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting. the date was of type string, so I used the query, select Name,to_char(date::date, 'yyyy') date from <tablename> (Column name is date and not DOB will this create any issue)

Comment: Put column name in double quotes, i.e. "date" and it will not be an issue. However using reserved words for column names is not a good idea at all. I have updated the answer.