# Grouping sales by month - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to group my total sales by month.

**In controller:**

```
@monthly_counts = Sales.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month, sum(price) AS total_price_per_month").group('month')
```

**In view:**

```
<% @monthly_counts.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.month %>
  <%= m.total_price_per_month %>
<% end %>
```

It worked well, but these codes grouped total sales from October 1 until November 1.
What i want is group from October 1 until October 31, and then create a new group from November 1 until November 30 and so on.
What should i do?? Thanks for advice!! :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `DATE_TRUNC`. Please see [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531577/how-to-extract-year-and-month-from-date-in-postgresql) for possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more refined version of this

```
@monthly_counts = Sales.select("created_at, sum(price) AS total_price_per_month").group('month(created_at)')
```

Comment: I got this error "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function month(timestamp without time zone) does not exist"