# How can I extract month and years using JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I hope you can help me.
I have this situation:

PostgreSQL
Table: Flags

```
id_flag (integer) | flag_type (smallint) | start_date (date)
1                   2                      2020-01-01
```

I have a FlagsRepository.java

```
public interface FlagsRepository extends JpaRepository<Flags, Integer> {
  @Query(value="select type_flag from web_flags where extract(month from start_date)=:month and extract(year from start_date)=:year"
  List<Flags> myFindUsingMonthAndYear( @Param("month") Integer month, @Param("year") Integer year);
}
```

When I execute using CommandLineRunner on my Application.java it returns an error: could not execute the query.

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: When I run the same through my mind, it tells me "cannot understand the issue without further details". Stack trace?? Spring config??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract year and month from date in PostgreSQL without using to\_char() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531577/how-to-extract-year-and-month-from-date-in-postgresql-without-using-to-char-fu)

Comment: Thanks guys but I got a solution using nativeQuery.